# Return customized UIButton in method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have a method that takes a UIButton, modifies its properties and returns a UIButton. However, it doesn't ever seem to be initialized. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the memory management here, but don't exactly know how to fix it. No runtime errors occur.

It is called like so...

```
newGameBtn = [self customButtonFromButton:newGameBtn
                                 withText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NEW GAME"]
                             withFontSize:22
                          withBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor]
                                 isSilent:YES];
[dashboardContainer addSubview:newGameBtn];
```

The method is defined as follows...

```
- (UIButton*) customButtonFromButton:(UIButton*)button withText:(NSString*)text withFontSize:(int)fontSize withBorderColor:(UIColor*)borderColor isSilent:(BOOL)isSilent {
    button = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Set properties from parameters
    // Other conditional custom stuff here

    return button;
}
```

NOTE: `newGameBtn` is of type UIButton* and is initialized with:
`newGameBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];`

Another option might be to subclass UIButton, but I figured I'd try to fix this since I've already walked down this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `+[UIButton buttonWithType:]` when creating buttons to get a properly initialized button.

Most classes are not properly initialized by the default `-[NSObject init]` method. So please look at the class reference, or superclass reference, for a usable initialization method.

In this case you should also set a `frame`.

Comment: +1. The factory method is the *only* way to get a correctly configured button. Using any of the init methods is relying on the current implementation which might change at any time. No way to set the button type, for example - which is a vital property. That's the reason why subclassing is not appropriate either.

Comment: Ah, in refactoring, I forgot to move the blasted frame. Yep. That did it. Note in my response to @Martin Ullrich that I was actually using buttonWithType: to init.

Answer (score 1):

You don't modify this button with your method, you're creating a completely new one with alloc-init!

If you want to change the button in your first argument just remove the first line of your method

Comment: I did actually try it that way, but still with no active button. I also tried newGameBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain]; before passing newGameBtn to the method and it too does not render anything.

Comment: I also tried newGameBtn = [[[UIButton alloc] init] retain]; before calling the method and that too did not work.